# Artikel in "Ein feste Burg"

Tags: article, adjective

Warum schreibt man

[*Ein feste Burg* ist unser Gott](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ein_feste_Burg_ist_unser_Gott,_BWV_80)

wenn *Burg* weiblich ist? Ich würde *eine* schreiben.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es fällt sofort auf, dass die volle moderne Form "eine feste Burg" nicht ins Versmaß und zur Melodie des Liedes passen würde.

Das Lied wurde im 16. Jahrhundert von Martin Luther geschrieben. Das Deutsch von Martin Luther ist zwar einer der Ursprünge für das moderne Hochdeutsch, aber es war bei der Orthografie und Grammatik noch lange noch nicht so weit in Regeln gefasst wie heute.

Auch heute kürzen die meisten deutschen mündlich gesprochenen Dialekte das Wort "eine" auf eine Silbe ab, je nach Region zum Beispiel als "an", "oan", "ne", "een" etc. Deshalb ist es nicht weiter überraschend, dass Luther, wo es passte, einfach auch eine einsilbige Form benutzen konnte.

Wenn man den Text der [Lutherbibel in der Version von 1545](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Luther,+Martin/Luther-Bibel+1545/Das+Alte+Testament/Die+Spr%C3%BCche+Salomonis/Spr%C3%BCche+18) ansieht, finden sich da auch Beispiele für das Wort "eine", z.B. Sprüche 18,11:

> Das gut des Reichen ist jm eine feste Stad / Vnd wie eine hohe maure vmb jn her.

Aber auch, ein paar Verse weiter:

> Wer ein Ehefraw findet / der findet was guts /Vnd kan guter ding sein im HERRN.

> Ein heimliche Gabe stillet den zorn / Vnd ein Geschenck im schos den hefftigen Grim.

Comment: Der Text ist identisch mit der Lutherübersetzung der Bibel, Überschrift zu [Psalm 46](https://www.bibleserver.com/LUT/Psalm46) von 1534. Ohne Nachweis, dass das Lied älter ist, ist das Versmaß-Argument damit nicht zwingend. Andere Vorkommen  in der Lutherübersetzung lassen zumindest erkennen, dass *Burg* auch damals feminin war und meist mit dem unbestimmten Artikel *eine* verwendet wurde.

Comment: @guidot: das "Versmaß-Argument" ist ja nur, dass "eine feste Burg" nicht ins Versmaß passen würde -- dazu braucht man nur den Text und evtl. die Melodie des Liedes anzugucken. Das Lied ist von vor 1529 (laut WP), die Psalmüberschrift ist deutlich  jünger, siehe z.B. https://lutheraner-steeden.de/die-besseren-psalmenueberschriften. Das Wort Burg kommt in dem Psalmtext selbst ja gar nicht vor, die Psalmüberschrift spielt vermutlich auf das Lied an.

Answer (score 5):

Nach der aktuell geltenden Grammatik wäre

> **Eine** feste Burg ist unser Gott.

korrekt.

Einige Quellen (siehe Wikipedia-Link in der Frage) verwenden die Schreibweise

> **Ein'** feste Burg ist unser Gott.

Das Apostroph in **Ein'** zeigt an, daß etwas weggelassen wurde. (Nämlich das fehlende **e**.) Dies ist aber anscheinend eine Anpassung an die aktuelle Grammatik, denn eine Version von 1545 (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ein_feste_Burg_ist_unser_Gott) enthält dies noch nicht.

Als dichterische Freiheit ist es allgemein üblich, Wörter an die Musik oder das Versmaß anzupassen. "Ein' feste Burg ist unser Gott" paßt besser zum Versmaß im Vergleich zur dritten Textzeile "Er hilft uns frei aus aller Not,". Die zweite Zeile "ein gute Wehr und Waffen." benutzt ebenfalls "ein" anstelle des heute korrekten "eine".

(Ob dies zur Zeit der Entstehung allgemein üblich oder bereits eine Verkürzung von war, ist mir nicht bekannt.)

Der Text stammt laut Wikipedia von vor 1529, also aus der Zeit der frühneuhochdeutschen Sprache, in der noch andere Regeln für Grammatik und Rechtschreibung galten. Dies kann man an der gedruckten Textfassung (siehe Wikipedia-Link oben) sehen.